wpa_supplicant.conf not working in Rasberry Pi 4
So i tried to change wifi based to wpa_supplicant.conf but it dont work in multiple wifi, when i tried using raspi-config wlan it work but dont automatic change based available and priority. And i just using ssh without monitor to change wifi with terminal command.
I adding line with this format
network={
  SSID=""
  PSW=""
  priority=2
}
I expecting it can work automatic based on priority if multiple and automatic connect with wpa_configuration or i can edit directly to file that raspi-config wlan saving info
